# Multiple calls to the same JPA model overwriting the object

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, persistence

I have a blob of Play Framework(1.2.5)/JPA code that goes like:

```
List<MyObject> nL = MyObject.find("uuid", SubscriptionReferrer).fetch();
MyObject n = nL.get(0);
n.subscriptions.add(SubscriptionReference);
n.save();
JPA.em().flush();
JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
```

Because it is called outside the realms of the controller I am asking JPA to write the record. Anyway basically someone subscribes to a product and this method gets called. But they can also subscribe to multiple products at the same time creating multiple individual calls to this method.

The problem I seem to have is that when the calls are run off in parallel, the

```
List<MyObject> nL = MyObject.find("uuid", SubscriptionReferrer).fetch();
MyObject n = nL.get(0);
```

bit is called and returns the object, but the object is individual to all calls, and when the save is committed, the last object wins, and all the others are overwritten.

==Edit==
Also, I do not know how many subscriptions will be passed because it comes from a 3rd party payment provider.

So, is there a sensible way of me saving all the updates to the object without me writing some additional caching layer?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: How do you want this to work?  If one updates name, and another updates it to a different value, there will always be a winner and a loser, and all changes could be based on data made stale from a previous change they didn't see.  I'd recommend you implement optimistic locking and handle the exceptions if it is not going to be common for the different threads to update the same object at the same time.  Otherwise you might need a form of pessimistic locking to synchronize the data reads and writes.

Answer (score 0):

You could "synchronize" your method, this would make sure the object is being fetched and updated in an atomic fashion. Using the transactions within JPA would also work.

Comment: You'll have to link to some samples or something because I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @magicaltrout - Using synchronized methods or code blocks http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Ah those Syncronsized :) I thought you meant the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Design!

Slept on it, and realised, even though its just a bunch of Strings its far easier to create a Subscription Model and persist them with a join back to the main object.

Thanks guys.